# Framework red after importing it into a workspace swift

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I have downloaded this https://github.com/MichelDeiman/Programming-Project-4_-Smashtag-Mentions Twitter project to use the Twitter.framework it comes with. When I open it from the download, it loads fine. However, when I move the Twitter.xcodeproj to my Xcode workspace, it turns the framework red and doesn't allow me to use it.

I have searched for a solution and think it has to do with finding the correct path for the framework but have been unsuccessful. Any thoughts?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Red means it hasn't been built yet. I suspect you can't use it because it hasn't been imported in the Build settings. I'd check there first. If it's imported correctly then it should built when you build the targets that refer to it.